# Installing PostgreSQL 9.1 on Red Hat 6.1 x86_64 requires already installed libs

Tags: postgresql, redhat, yum

I'm following what is described [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation#Configure_your_YUM_repository) to install PostgreSQL 9.1 on a Red Hat 6.1
When I launch yum install postgresql91-server it complains that libssl.so.10 and  libcrypto.so.10 are missing, while I've verified that they're available under /usr/lib64/

Here it is the errors I get:

> postgresql91-server-9.1.12-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
>
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Error: Package: postgresql91-libs-9.1.12-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg91)
>
> ```
>       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
> ```
>
> Error: Package: postgresql91-server-9.1.12-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg91)
>
> ```
>       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
> ```
>
> Error: Package: postgresql91-libs-9.1.12-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg91)
>
> ```
>       Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
> ```
>
> Error: Package: postgresql91-server-9.1.12-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg91)
>
> ```
>       Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
> ```
>
> Error: Package: postgresql91-9.1.12-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg91)
>
> ```
>       Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
> ```
>
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>   You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

What do I miss?

Comment: At a guess, the RPMs were built for the current patch release of RHEL 6. Update to RHEL 6.4 or rebuild the RPMs against 6.1.

Comment: Do you mean that postgresql91-server package is looking for different libssl and libcrypto libs?
rpm --query --whatprovides libssl.so.10 tells me that no package is offering it, while rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 says it comes from openssl-1.0.0-10.el6.x86_64.
I've exluded postgresql from rhmplugin and got it from http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php

Comment: Yes, specifically, I think it expects newer versions available in 6.4.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue while trying to install Postgres 9.1 on a CentOS 6.4 machine. I was able to fix the issue by updating the version of openssl that was installed.

A similar problem is described here: [Dependency Resolution Fails on Installed Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518183/dependency-resolution-fails-on-installed-library/22574024#22574024)

At the time of this writing, openssl-1.0.1e-15 is available in the CentOS (6) repository, here:  [openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64.rpm](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64.rpm) and provides the libssl and libcrypto dependencies that were previously missing.
To install, you can:

```
sudo yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Again, if the version in the CentOS repo changes, that URL may no longer be valid.

Ok, now for the gory details...

Originally, my machine had openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64.rpm installed, which didn't provide all of the packages my postgres rpm was requiring:

```
> rpm -q --provides openssl
config(openssl) = 1.0.0-27.el6_4.2
...
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)
...  
libssl.so.10()(64bit)  
...
```

After installing the newer openssl version:

```
> rpm -q --provides openssl
config(openssl) = 1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4
...
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)  
libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)  
libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)  
libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)  
...
libssl.so.10()(64bit)  
libssl.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)  
libssl.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)  
libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)  
...
```

And all are happy now...

Bottom line, install a newer version of openssl and it should provide the dependencies you need. Good Luck!

Comment: How do you made the openssl upgrade?
Thanks